# can PHP do something like p($i) and it prints "$i is 5" -- C and Ruby can... (that is, to print out "$i" automatically)

Tags: php, c, ruby, debugging, printing

I was wondering if PHP can do this as there seems to be no good solution to it yet:

```
p($i)
```

and it will print

```
$i is 5
```

and

```
p(1 + 2)
```

will print

```
1 + 2 is 3
```

and

```
p($i * 2)  =>  $i * 2 is 10  
p(3 * factorial(3))  =>  3 * factorial(3) is 18
```

C and Ruby both can do it... in C, it can be done by stringification, and in Ruby, there is a solution using `p{'i'}` or `p{'1 + 2'}` (by passing the block with the binding over, to do an eval)... I wonder in PHP, is it possible too?

Comment: Another "Ruby is better then PHP" question? :)

Comment: @CsabaKétszeri there's no question, it is ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it could be done by taking a backtrace then loading and tokenizing the file that calls `p()`.  I wouldn't call it a "good" solution though.

Of course you could stringify it yourself...

```
p('$i');

function p($str) 
{
    echo $str, " = ", eval("return ($str);");
}
```

Comment: Using `var_export` would be nice.

Comment: stingify it myself... that's so funny

Answer (score 2):

If you mess with the string to make it into a return statement, you can use [eval](http://php.net/eval)...

```
function p($expr)
{
   $php="return {$expr};";
   echo "$expr is ".eval($php)."\n";
}


p("1+2");
```

Works for simple expressions, but if you tried to reference a variable in your $expr, then it wont find it inside the scope of function p() - a little hack like the following can help:

```
function p($expr)
{
   $php="return {$expr};";
   $php=preg_replace('/\\$(\w+)/', '$GLOBALS[\'$1\']', $php);


   echo "$expr is ".eval($php)."\n";
}

$x=5;
p('$x+4');
```

Here we've search for variable references in the code and turned them into $GLOBALS array references. The expression `$x+4` is turned into `return  $GLOBALS['x']+4;`

Not sure I'd ever want to see this in production code though :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you pass in a string, you can use [eval](http://us.php.net/eval) to do the calculation.

Comment: the function won't be able to evaluate the global though

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no

The problem with eval() based solutions is scope. The following won't work:

```
function p($expr)
{
   $php="return {$expr};";
   echo "$expr is ".eval($php)."\n";
}

$i = 10;

p('$i + 1');
```

because $i won't be in scope when eval() is called.